# undefined variable during send mail with attachment in laravel

Tags: laravel

Undefined variable: `pdf_show` whenever I try to send mail with `$pdf_show` attachment.

```
$pdf = View::make('site.bill', compact('invoice_bill'))->render();
            $pdf_show =  PDF::load($pdf, 'A4', 'portrait')->output();

        $msg = Config::get('ashram.delivered');
            Mail::send('blank', array('msg' => Config::get('ashram.delivered'),'id'=>$id,'is_approve'=>$is_approve), function($message){
            $message->to(Request::segment(3), Input::get('name'))->cc('subhankarbhattacharjee56@yahoo.in')->subject('Delivery')//;
            ->attach($pdf_show , "Tax Invoice");
        });
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `use($pdf_show)` to your mail function

```php
$pdf = View::make('site.bill', compact('invoice_bill'))->render();
$pdf_show = PDF::load($pdf, 'A4', 'portrait')->output();

$msg = Config::get('ashram.delivered');

Mail::send('blank', array('msg' => Config::get('ashram.delivered'),'id'=>$id,'is_approve'=>$is_approve), function($message) use ($pdf_show) {
    $message->to(Request::segment(3), Input::get('name'))->cc('subhankarbhattacharjee56@yahoo.in')->subject('Delivery')
            ->attachData($pdf_show , "Tax Invoice");
});
```

Comment: After using use($pdf_show) to mail function Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Message::attach() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: I have done it by using ->attachData($pdf_show , "Tax Invoice");

Comment: Okay, can you mark the answer as complete, since it fixed your initial problem, with the variable not being accessible inside the Mail function